# How to set a certain location to limit the drag able and resizable element of a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have jQuery code that makes a div resizeable and draggable across the body and works perfectly.

what I am trying to implement is:

1. Set a location, I'm my case between my vertical `.v1` and horizontal `.vh` line, in which the div element can only be draggable on that scope.
2. Set a maximum width and height the div can be resized inside that set location.

My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
$("#framewrap").mouseup(function() {
  $(this).find('iframe').fadeIn('slow');
}).mousedown(function() {
  $(this).find('iframe').hide();
});

$(function() {
  $("#framewrap").resizable().draggable();
});
```

```css
#framewrap {
  padding: 10px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-color: aqua;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #2b2d2f;
}

#frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.vl {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4.7%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vh {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72%;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
  height: 2.5px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<iframe id="frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/roRvfs_30c4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="vl"></div>
<div class="vh"></div>
```

Comment: I assume you're using jQueryUI so I added them to the snippet from the methods being called. If you're not using that library please update the snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would advise, for Draggable, you review: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement and for Resizable https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area Additionally, in yoolur example, I do not see an element with the id `framewarp`